# Is there a kind of log on Azure SQL Server to check when some function was created/dropped?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Some functions that I created on my Azure SQL Server database suddenly disappeared, is there some way (some kind of log) where I can check when it happened (maybe also who did that too)?

Comment: Check [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/determining-how-a-schema-change-occurred)

Comment: Check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current

Comment: The report told on the post doesn't exist on my database, neither **sys.traces** or **sys.event_log**.

Comment: Well that's bogus. Looks like you might have to set up an Audit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing#subheading-1

Answer (score 0):

Reports that are available on SQL Server instances rely on traces that are not available on Azure SQL Database. To monitor schema changes you can do a few things.

One option is using DDL Triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR CREATE_FUNCTION, DROP_FUNCTION, ALTER_FUNCTION  
AS   
   PRINT 'Save change on a log'   
   SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

Another option is using Extended Events to track schema changes as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-xevent-db-diff-from-svr#code-samples).

Finally, Azure Database Auditing can help with schema changes and dropped objects. Below an example:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing `
 -State Enabled `
 -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname" `
 -ServerName "ssqlinstancename" `  #ssqlinstancename.database.windows.net
 -StorageAccountName "strageaccountname" `
 -DatabaseName "dbname" `
 -AuditActionGroup 'SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP' `
 -RetentionInDays 8 `
 -AuditAction "DELETE ON schema::dbo BY [public]"
```